# Adding a python colorbar but certain values are fixed to a color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I have a 2D array of data (lets call this `X`) where the values can range from anywhere between `-2000` and `2000`. The array also includes "empty" data, which I have implemented by using `NaN`s. I would like to use a custom-listed colormap to represent the data, where the `NaN`s are "empty" or white. I would also like to be able to dynamically alter the colorbar limits `v_min` and `v_max` which I have successfully done (see `colormap_plot`).

[image: [colormap_plot][1])]

However, I would like to specify that values in `X` between `-25` and `25` should be colored grey, regardless of the range of the colorbar. I have managed to do this by creating a second array (lets call this `Y`) of the same size as `X`, whose values are RGB codes dependent on the corresponding value inside `X`. This gives the result that I require (see `plot_with_grey`).

[image: plot_with_grey]

However, I would like to have the same colorbar from the `colormap_plot` at the side of the `plot_with_grey`, so I would love a solution that would allow me to solve this.

Comment: Please see [reprex] and [edit] your question with code and sample data.

Comment: Less description of what the code does, more code. It is difficult to understand why you do not define the initial colormap with grey for values of -25 to 25.